# Trying to implement a Cloud Function on firebase but get an error for undefined variable

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have the function below I have implemented and deployed to my cloud functions in my firebase project but upon execution, it causes me an error in the function log of the firebase console;

```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'profileImgUrl' of undefined
```

I understand the meaning of the error it generates, but I don't understand why my user variable will be undefined

Here is the function below:

```
exports.eventInvites = functions.firestore
.document('Events/{eventId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const eventData = snap.data();
  const eventId = context.params.eventId;
  const invitees = eventData.invitees;
  let user;
  db.doc(`Users/${eventData.createdBy}`).get().then(doc => {
    var data = doc.data();
    user = data; // updated user data but still get undefined
    return user;
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
  if (invitees !== undefined || invitees.length > 0) {
    invitees.forEach(invitee => {
      db.collection('Users').doc(invitee).collection('feed').doc().set({
        date: new Date(),
        image: user.profileImgUrl, // error occurs here, says user is undefined
        summary: `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName} invited you to an event`,
        extraText: `${eventData.eventName}: ${eventData.eventDetails} `,
        extraImages: [
          eventData.eventImgUrl
        ]
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message)
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get()` is asynchronous therefore the code after it is getting executed before. To solve this, you can put all the code inside `get()`:

```
db.doc(`Users/${eventData.createdBy}`).get().then(doc => {
    var data = doc.data();
    user = data;
    if (invitees !== undefined || invitees.length > 0) {
      invitees.forEach(invitee => {
        db.collection('Users').doc(invitee).collection('feed').doc().set({
          date: new Date(),
          image: user.profileImgUrl,
          summary: `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName} invited you to an event`,
          extraText: `${eventData.eventName}: ${eventData.eventDetails} `,
          extraImages: [
            eventData.eventImgUrl
          ]
        })
      });
    }
    return user;
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
```